# Yii pagination not moving to last page

Tags: php, yii, pagination

i did custom pagination using in Yii. i have 33 items. but yii pagination not working for that last 3 items.

Sample Code:

```
            $total = 33;
            $pages =new CPagination($total);
            $pages->setPageSize($this->pagesize);
            $pages->setCurrentPage($page);

            $start = ($pages->currentPage-1)*$pages->pageSize;
            $images = array_slice($images,$start,($pages->pageSize));
```

Comment: What do you mean by 'not working'? Are the last 3 pages not visible in your pagination? Are there no results on the last 3 pages?

Answer (score 0):

Here is your code

```
    $total = 33;
    $pages =new CPagination($total);
    $pages->setPageSize($this->pagesize); // $this->pagesize = 10

    $start = $pages->currentPage * $pages->pageSize;
    $images = array_slice($images,$start,($pages->pageSize));
```